# How to find elapsed time for two trains to cross each other when they travel in the same direction?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors, kinematics

The problem is as follows:

> Two trains which have different lengths each are going to meet by
> traveling on different tracks with speeds $v_{1}$ and $v_{2}$
> respectively. They take $20\,s$ to cross each other. If they go to
> meet with speeds $v_{1}$ and $\frac{8}{5}v_{2}$ respectively they
> require $15\,s$. How long will they need to cross each other if they
> travel on the same direction with speeds $v_{1}$ and $v_{2}$?

The answer in my book is : $180\,s$

I assumed that the catch here is to make a system of equations. What I could spot here was:

$d_1: \textrm{length of the first train}$
$d_2: \textrm{length of the second train}$

But I came stuck at how to relate when they are traveling in opposite directions.
Since both are moving against each other I'm assuming that their speeds subtract from each other, but how does this account for the length of each train?.

I thought this:

$\textrm{v_total} \times t_{cross}=d_{1}+d_2$

$\textrm{v_total= sum of the vectors from the speeds}$

$(v_1-v_2)20= d_1+d_2$

But this doesn't specifically indicates which is faster.

The other equation would be

$\left(v_1-\frac{8}{5}v_2\right)15=d_1+d_2$

Dividing both equations I'm getting:

$\frac{v_1-v_2}{5v_1-8v_2}=\frac{3}{20}$

Rearranging this results in:

$20v_{1}-20v_{2}=15v_1-24v_2$

Which is reduced to:

$5v_{1}+4v_2=0$

Which gets a negative quantity:

$v_{1}=-\frac{4}{5}v_2$

But from this I became confused exactly on what to do?. Can someone help me here?. Am I understanding this the correct way?. Is my assumption regarding the subtraction in speeds correct?. Because that's the part where I'm struggling the most. All and all, what would be the most appropiate way to solve this?. If a sketch could accompany the solution it would help a lot, since I'm getting confused. Any help please?.

Comment: Well, hypothetically one train could be travelling backwards.  But that almost certainly is not the case.

Comment: If the trains are moving toward each other they aproach with a combined (added) speed.  Imaging two cars are $50$ miles apart heading toward each other and $30$ and $20$ mph.  In one hour one has gone $30$ miles and the other $20$ so together the have gone $50$miles.... in one hour.  If you subtract you would have two cars head toward each other at equal speed .... and they never get any close!  That doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

If they are traveling in opposite directions, the speeds *add* to get the crossing speed.  Transform to the frame of train $2$.  In that frame train $1$ is traveling at $v_1+v_2$.  The front of train $1$ has to travel the total length of both trains before the crossing is done, so the time it takes is $\frac {d_1+d_2}{v_1+v_2}$.  With this correction your approach is correct.

Comment: My problem is **how** do I tell if the transformation to the frame of the train is correct. In my attempt what I thought it was that the speed of the trains was not crucial, Where in the problem should I spot that the frame **should be** for the second train?. Is it from getting a negative result in the end?. In my approach I subtracted the speeds I didn't add them. I'm still stuck. :(

Comment: You are looking for the relative speed of the trains.  You would subtract if they were going in the same direction.  If one were at 60 and the other at 59 the relative speed would be 1.  If they were going opposite the relative speed would be 119.  The error came when you subtracted instead of adding the speeds.  Think of cars passing on the highway.

Comment: Imagine one of the trains is standing still and instead the entire word is moving at it with the speed it would have.  So the other train have $v_2$ and the world has $v_1$ and the world adds $v_1$ to it.  So the trains have combined speed of $v_1+ v_2$

Answer (score 0):

Notice in every scenario the distance traveled is the same.  They must start by touching noses.  Then the longer train's nose will touch the shorter train's butt.   Then the long train goes its distance so the longer train's butt touches the shorter trains's butt.  Together combined they travel $d_1 + d_2$.  Always.  SO let's just call that $D$

So the time it takes is $t =\frac {D}{v_1 + v_2}$.

So we have $t_1 = \frac {D}{v_1 + v_2} = 20s$  or $v_1 + v_2 = \frac D{20}$.

And $t_2 = \frac {D}{v_1 + \frac 85 v_2} = 15s$ or $v_1 + \frac 85 v_2 = \frac D{15}$.

Solving for $v_1$ and $v_2$

$20v_1 + 20v_2 = D$ and $15v_1 + 24v_2 = D$ so

$60v_1 + 60v_2 = 3D$ and $60V_1 + 96v_2 = 4D$ so

$36v_2 = D$ and $v_2 = \frac 1{36}D$ and sso

$20v_1 + \frac 59 D= D$ and $15v_1 + \frac 23D=D$ so

$20v_1 = \frac 49D$ and $15v_1 = \frac 13D$ and $v_1=\frac 4{9*20}D = \frac 1{3*15}D=\frac 1{45}D$

If they are going in the same direction then the faster one will be overtaking the other at a relative rate of the difference of there speeds.

So $t_3 = \frac {D}{v_2 - v_1} =\frac {D}{\frac 1{36}D-\frac 1{45}D}=\frac {45*36}{45-36}=$

$\frac {9*5*36}{9} = 210$ seconds.